# get_global_id does not start at 0

Tags: c++, opencl

Hi all I am having trouble with one of my opencl programs, basically in the kernel I have the following:

```
__kernel void add(__global const double* A, __global const double* B, __global double* C) {
int id = get_global_id(0);
printf("id = %d\n", id);
C[id] = A[id] + B[id];
```

The printf was added to me after this very basic kernel failed ... for some reason the following code(or the code above):

```
try {
    //Part 4 - memory allocation
    //host - input
    std::vector<double> A = workingSet; //C++11 allows this type of initialisation
    std::vector<double> B = workingSet; 

    size_t vector_elements = A.size();//number of elements
    size_t vector_size = A.size()*sizeof(double);//size in bytes

    //host - output
    std::vector<double> C(vector_elements);

    //device - buffers
    cl::Buffer buffer_A(kernel.context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, vector_size);
    cl::Buffer buffer_B(kernel.context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, vector_size);
    cl::Buffer buffer_C(kernel.context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, vector_size);

    //Part 5 - device operations

    //5.1 Copy arrays A and B to device memory
    kernel.queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_A, CL_TRUE, 0, vector_size, &A[0]);
    kernel.queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_B, CL_TRUE, 0, vector_size, &B[0]);

    //5.2 Setup and execute the kernel (i.e. device code)
    cl::Kernel kernel_add = cl::Kernel(kernel.program, "add");
    kernel_add.setArg(0, buffer_A);
    kernel_add.setArg(1, buffer_B);
    kernel_add.setArg(2, buffer_C);

    kernel.queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_add, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(vector_elements), cl::NullRange);

    //5.3 Copy the result from device to host
    kernel.queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer_C, CL_TRUE, 0, vector_size, &C[0]);

    //std::cout << "A = " << A << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "B = " << B << std::endl;
    std::cout << "C = " << C << std::endl;
}
catch (cl::Error err) {
    std::cerr << "ERROR: " << err.what() << ", " << getErrorString(err.err()) << std::endl;
}
```

Seems to get a global_id starting around 14K sometimes 15L, workingset is a std::vector of doubles (around .. 18K of them)

the kernel is initilized elsewhere and passed to that main codeblock via this code:

```
    kernel_set myKern;

//Part 2 - host operations
//2.1 Select computing devices
cl::Context context = GetContext(platform_id, device_id);

//create a queue to which we will push commands for the device
cl::CommandQueue queue(context);

//2.2 Load & build the device code
cl::Program::Sources sources;

AddSources(sources, "kernel.cl");

cl::Program program(context, sources);

program.build();

myKern.error    = false;
myKern.context  = context;
myKern.queue    = queue;
myKern.program  = program;

return myKern;
```

As I have no reliable global_id I cannot figure out what to do

Comment: I am quite sure (and I could even bet) that kernel ids start at 0 (unless you are using offset). Can you give us the base you are using to conclude that they do not start at 0?

Comment: Hi guys, well as you can see I added a printf to my kernel, an I literally just redirected my program to a text file, the lowest ID printed is always in the 14K range. However since I posted this I have found if I do: std::vector<double> workingSet = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 } instead of using the one with thousands of entries, the global id starts at 0 as expected

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong with your code. Only thing I can think of is your driver doesn't fully support OpenCL 1.2, and you need to enable the Double Precision extension manually (or your driver has a bug). Add the following to the top of your kernel (minus quotes): "#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable"

Comment: @ScottMichaud its a GTX 950 so it really should

Comment: @VeronikaPrüssels Oh really... and its just showing me the tail ends of the buffer, but.. damn just realised 18732 entries in that vertex array, its jsut showing the last records... thank you :)

Comment: @VeronikaPrüssels That is the answer .... how do I actually mark that as the answer, I seem to be able to 'answer your question' but not mark yours as the answer

Comment: @daemon Do you still have the answer for this and can add it here? Looks like VeronikaPrüssel's comment was removed for some reason.

Comment: @SimonWarta Looking at my notification history I cannot even see what Veronikas answer was unfortunately :( and I have no recollection of what the answer was - wonder if the waybackmachine has a cache of it